# Re-ordering the columns in a HTML Table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

There is a html table in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GXa25/) which is created as

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th>Sl.No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Dec 2013</th>
        <th>Feb 2014</th>
        <th>Jan 2014</th>
        <th>Mar 2014</th>
        <th>Nov 2013</th>
        <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>bar</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>23</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How to re-order the columns using jquery so that the order of the columns in new table becomes `Sl.No, Name, Nov 2013, Dec 2013, Jan 2014, Feb 2014, Mar 2014, Total` Also the month columns are generated dynamically by server based on date selection (`From` and `To` dates)

Comment: Why don't you sort the data on the server?

Comment: I suggest you use `ORDER BY ` in the Query you use to retrieve data !
This reduces the JS load if there's any on client side !

Comment: @undefined - Me sorted data in server side. But at client side it taking the order in alphabetical manner. ie like `Dec 2013` `Feb 2014` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = $('th').sort(function(a, b) {
   return new Date(a.innerHTML) > new Date(b.innerHTML);
}).map(function() { return this.cellIndex }).get();

$('tr').each(function() {
    $(this.cells).sort(function(a, b) {
        a = $.inArray(a.cellIndex, arr);
        b = $.inArray(b.cellIndex, arr);
        return a > b;
    }).prependTo(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZR5W7/