# sorting the columns of html table

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table

I have a html table in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AEvpd/1/) and trying to sort the columns using jquery with reference to [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853494/re-ordering-the-columns-in-a-html-table-using-jquery) as,

```
var arr = $('th').filter(function() {
   return (new Date(this.innerHTML)).getDate();
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    return new Date(a.innerHTML) > new Date(b.innerHTML);
}).map(function () {
    return this.cellIndex
}).get();

$('tr').each(function () {
    $(this).children().filter(function(){
       return $.inArray(this.cellIndex, arr)> -1;
    }).sort(function (a, b) {
        a = $.inArray(a.cellIndex, arr);
        b = $.inArray(b.cellIndex, arr);
        return a > b;
    }).insertBefore(this.lastElementChild);
});
```

It works fine upto 10 month columns. But if the number of month column exceeds 10, the sorting will collapse as given in fiddle. How can i fix this?

Comment: not sure how this can possibly work. The dates returned are all invalid. Can verify by logging them to console within your sort or filter. Try  `console.log(new Date('Feb 2014'))` as proof

Comment: I want to sort based on months. I referred this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AEvpd/ given in [this stack answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853494/re-ordering-the-columns-in-a-html-table-using-jquery)

Comment: define sort by months, years don't matter? As far as I can see the demo's don't work. Also what about the non date columns you have?

Comment: the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AEvpd/ working fine in chrome

Comment: OK, I had not checked chrome and was raising concerns based on Firefox not accepting abbreviated dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the entries from the array `arr`, you will find out the ordering is wrong. This has something to do with the sorting function.

The sorting function in the original code returns `a > b` given inputs `(a, b)`. In the case `a <= b`, the sorting function will return `0`, so if we have the strict inequality`a < b`, the sorting function will suggest that `a` is as large as `b` (because it returns 0), this is where the incorrectness arises.

You may try the following code:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AEvpd/2/)

```
var arr = $('th').filter(function() {
   return (new Date(this.innerHTML)).getDate();
}).sort(function (a, b) {
    aDate = new Date(a.innerHTML);
    bDate = new Date(b.innerHTML);
    if (aDate > bDate) {
        return 1;
    } else if (aDate < bDate) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}).map(function () {
    return this.cellIndex
}).get();

$('tr').each(function () {
    $(this).children().filter(function(){
       return $.inArray(this.cellIndex, arr)> -1;
    }).sort(function (a, b) {
        a = $.inArray(a.cellIndex, arr);
        b = $.inArray(b.cellIndex, arr);
        if (a > b) {
            return 1;
        } else if (a < b) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }).insertBefore(this.lastElementChild);
});
```

Comment: I want to sort based on months. I referred this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AEvpd/ given in [this stack answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22853494/re-ordering-the-columns-in-a-html-table-using-jquery)

Comment: Does the year matter in sorting or not? Is `Oct 2013` coming after `Jun 2014` what you want?

Comment: Yes. Month and year. Just as in the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AEvpd/. `Oct 2013` should come before `Jun 2014`

Comment: Have you checked out the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AEvpd/2/) I post yet? If so, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Yes... working fine as required in chrome. But it not working in Mozilla.

Comment: It appears Firefox has problem with supporting `.innerHTML`, you can substitute it with the jQuery function `.html()`. Moreover, Firefox regards date strings of the form `Oct 2013` as invalid input for `Date`'s constructor, so you need to create your own helper function to create a valid `Date` object from `Oct 2013`.

Comment: I have added a date `01` to make it work with mozilla http://jsfiddle.net/AEvpd/3/